# pass variables from zf2 helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to pass variables to some.phtml from zf2 view helper.
I want to return some data inside my view/application/some/some.phtml

```
 public function __invoke($request)
    {

    }
```

can anyone suggest?

Comment: You should make your question more clearn. What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
public function __invoke($request) 
{
    $myVar = 'these';
    $myOtherVar = 'probably';
    $anotherVar = 'arent really strings';

    return [$myVar, $myOtherVar, $anotherVar];
}
```

But I would probably try to refactor so this is all done in the controller. But if you state the actual problem you are having and what you are trying to achieve you will probably get a better answer